# GPU or CPU used for VCL graphics-based commands?

Tags: delphi, graphics, vcl

After searching for meaningful documentation and although the following are all root of VCL GRAPHICS, I'm trying to validate if a GPU or CPU are used for the following VCL commands (on a Windows Server)

1. PngImage.assign(SomeMemoryStream);
2. PngImage.canvas.TextOut(5,5,'Lee K');.
3. JpgImage.assign(PngImage)
4. the compression processing of the TJpgImage

knowing the above would determine the minimal specs for both the required CPU and graphics card.

Thanks in advance

Comment: No minimal specs required for any of this.

Comment: Well, it is possible that the OP needs to process N images per second, for some large value of N.

Comment: Have you ever considered using [Image32](https://github.com/AngusJohnson/Image32) library. It can use both CPU and GPU based hardware acceleration and has no dependencies of other libraries. Therefore you can use it either in VCL, FMX, Console or even from Service application.

Comment: @SilverWarior we are entering production tomorrow!  but thanks

Comment: @zaaaibon If you source enters Production Tomorrow: Your only option will be throw money at single core cpu power.

Comment: skia 4 delphi could be a solution. (especailly for Textout) BUT i havent worked with it. image en could also be a soltion for jpg compression and Png to jpg Conversion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GDI has been developed when a lot of computers had no ability to install anything similar to modern GPUs. TCanvas in VCL is just a thin wrapper around GDI, so it does not require GPU and does all operations on CPU.

Comment: @Quelltextknecht  If each  users creates a new thread/job, and the thread/job does the processing, there is no reason for 2CPU's - each with 32-cores not to be more effective than a single CPU.   Am I missing something ?